# Python - repetition of the task

Tags: python

I have problem with my first python program , I can't make the task repeat. I would like it to be an option to repeat the task or finish it. I need to add a selection option (either repeat the task again or close the program) Can anyone help me ?

```
powitanie = input("Podaj swoje imię")
powitanie2= input("Cześć " + powitanie + " miło mi Ciebie poznać, jest to program przeliczający waluty. "
                                              "Czy jesteś zainteresowany/zainteresowana")
if powitanie2 == "Tak" or powitanie2 == "tak":
    print("Dobrze w takim razie podaj walutę, którą chcesz przeliczyć (Do wyboru masz dolar, funt, złotówka)")
else:
    print("Dobrze w takim razie dziękuje i życzę miłego dnia")
    import sys
    sys.exit(0)

# TASK START HERE AGAIN

waluta = input("Waluta na którą chcesz przeliczyć: ")
if waluta == "dolar" or waluta == "Dolar":
    print("Wybrałeś/aś pierwszą walutę dolar, na jaką walutę chcesz ją przeliczyć? (funt, złotówka)")
elif waluta == "funt" or waluta == "Funt":
    print("Wybrałeś/aś pierwszą walutę funt, na jaką walutę chcesz ją przeliczyć? (dolar, złotówka)")
elif waluta == "złotówka" or waluta == "Złotówka":
    print ("Wybrałeś/aś pierwszą walutę złotówka, na jaką walutę chcesz ją przeliczyć? (dolar, funt)")
else:
    print("Wybrałeś/aś walutę której nie obsługujemy")

waluta2 = input("Waluta na którą chcesz przeliczyć: ")
if waluta == waluta2:
        print("Kwota będzie taka sama :)")
elif waluta2 == "dolar" or waluta2 =="Dolar":
    print("Wybrałeś/aś drugą walutę dolar, jaką kwotę chciałabyś/chciałbyś przeliczyć?")
elif waluta2 == "funt" or waluta2 == "Funt":
    print("Wybrałeś/aś drugą walutę funt, jaką kwotę chciałabyś/chciałbyś przeliczyć?")
elif waluta2 == "złotówka" or waluta2 == "Złotówka":
    print ("Wybrałeś/aś drugą walutę złotówka, jaką kwotę chciałabyś/chciałbyś przeliczyć?")
else:
    print("Wybrałeś/aś walutę której nie obsługujemy")

print("Kwota: ")
suma = float (input())
if suma <= 0:
    print("Kwota nie może być mniejsza ani równa 0")
elif suma > 0:
    print ("Kwota którą podałeś to " + str(suma))
else:
    print("Musisz podać kwotę")

print("Wpisz po jakim kursie chcesz przeliczyć pieniądze: ")
kurs = float(input())

podsumowanie = input("Podsumujmy wybrałeś/aś walutę " + waluta + " żeby przeliczyć ją na walutę " + waluta2 + " a wartość którą chcesz przeliczyć to "
    + str(suma) + ". Całość rozliczamy po kursie: " + str(kurs) + " Czy to się zgadza?" )
if podsumowanie == "tak" or podsumowanie == "Tak":
    print()
elif podsumowanie == "nie" or podsumowanie == "Nie":
    print()
else: print("Musisz odpowiedzieć tak lub nie")

rozliczenie = suma * kurs
całość= print("Przeliczenie : " + str(suma) + " " + waluta + " = " + str(kurs) + " " + waluta2)
```

## question about you want repetition this task

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use cycle in this case, like

```
do_again = True
while do_again:
    ...  # place for your code
    do_again = input('Repeat again?\n') == 'yes'
```

Comment: File "C:/Users/Ewelina/PycharmProjects/untitled1/przelicznik.py", line 13
    waluta = input("Waluta na którą chcesz przeliczyć: ")
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Fix your indents.

Answer (score 1):

You would wrap your task in a `for` or `while` loop, depending on how the condition is defined for stopping. It is not clear to me if the repetition is something determined programmatically or if it depends on user input. In any case, the loop is defined before the code block to be repeated, not at the end of it.